# Acces data from service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service where I pass some data on click what works great, but now I wanna pull that data from the service and add it to a scope in another controller and just log everytime there is something added with the $watch function.

My service:

```
app.service('infoService', function() {
    var currentInfo = [];
    return this.method = function(data){
        return currentInfo = data;
    };
});
```

Where I try to pull the data

```
app.controller('clickController', function($scope, infoService) {
    $scope.data = infoService.method();
    $scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    });
});
```

The only thing I currently see the last hour are errors and errors.

Comment: Can you be specific about the errors that you are seeing?

Comment: create plnkr to replicate this problem!

Comment: yes ofcourse, it keeps saying that the method is not a function, when I call it in the controller. If I log the data in the service there are no problems whatsover.

Comment: how could you log the data in the service when you can't call that method in your controller?

Comment: I dont know, I just update the service on a click with new data. and wanna pul that updated data out the service.

Comment: You need to create that [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). But the most obvious problem here is that you are creating a `service` rather than using the `factory`. Factories will create singleton objects where you can store data across the lifetime of the application

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove the return statement from your service

```
this.method = function(data){
    return currentInfo = data;
};
```

then you should be able to call function in your service

hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, thought also. But already tried that, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the watch on the return value of the service, like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return infoService.method(); }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    });
```